# How see the converted sql from ActiveRecord method in view, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I will be happy if someone clear doubt, I can see objects in view by
using `<%= debug @object %>` and lot of methods is there apart from view 
like `.to_yml`, etc

Is there any method available for seeing the converted sql from
ActiveRecord method in view, etc. Although I can find it in console but
it will confuse when we run multiple queries..

example:

```
User.find :all
```

it will produce

`SELECT * FROM users;`

in output console

But i want it in view are any other specific point like `yml` , etc ?

Answer (score 0):

This great gem will privide you with the info you're looking for plus many others:

https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug

It consists in a debug bar at the top of each page in development.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 you can call to_sql on a relation

```
User.where(:name => :bob).to_sql # => "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`name` = 'bob')"
```

You can render that into a view or anywhere else you like.